# Why addEventListener to 'select' element don not work?

Tags: javascript

I want select to another option ,it will console.log 2222 in Console,but when I choose to another,it don't console, so why?

```js
let mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
mySelect.addEventListener('change', print());

function print() {
  console.log(2222);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are trying to pass the return value of `print`, not the function `print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, when added event listener to the element `document.getElementById('mySelect')` it is being executed the function `print()` and that is why you see the result in the console..

What you want is to use the [event listener callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback).. In your case is the function `print`, but should be used  without the parentheses

Code:

```js
document
  .querySelector('#mySelect')
  .addEventListener('change', print);

function print() { 
  console.log(2222);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Or your can use directly an ES6 [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Code:

```js
document
  .querySelector('#mySelect')
  .addEventListener('change', () => console.log(2222));
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a solution to the "addEventListener"-problem for change-triggers, i came to the following, very simple solution:

```
$("select").on("change", function(event){
        console.log("ble");
        validate(event.target);
        checkWeiter();
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Use [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event instead.

It will trigger the provided function every time the selected value is changed.

```js
function print() {
    console.log(2222);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="print()">
    <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
```